# how to put one listview inside another listview in java file in android?

Tags: android

I have an  xml file with a gallery and listview named main.xml.Another xml file with webimageview and listview named list.xml.Now I need to attach the main.xml  to the listview in list.xml in java file.how can i do that?pls help with some ideas..

Comment: Better u put that in xml only

Comment: ALSO CHECK THIS  EXPANDABLE LISTVIEW http://coderzheaven.com/2011/04/expandable-listview-in-android-using-simpleexpandablelistadapter-a-simple-example/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put scrollable things in other scrollable things and get reliable results. Please consider another UI approach.